# Button not replaced with alternative button on mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to make the desktop button disappear on web view.

The first image below is the full view of the website, and the image button size.
[image]

The first button did not disappear on mobile view.

[image]

```
#menu-item-242{
      background-color:#e74c3c;
      padding: 2px 5px 0px 30px;
      border:none;
      border-radius:2px;
      color:white;
      text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
<ul id="menu-secondary-items" class="menu-items">
<li id="menu-item-242" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-242"><a href="#">Business</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

**Update**

```
@media only screen and (min-width:800px) {
    .menu > .wrap {
        display: block!important;
    }

    .menu- toggle {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .menu-items {
        zoom: 1;
    }

        .menu-items::before, .menu-items::after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
        }

        .menu-items::after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .menu-items > ul {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 60px auto;
        }

        .menu-items li li a {
            -webkit-transition: all 0 ease 0;
            -moz-transition: all 0 ease 0;
            -o-transition: all 0 ease 0;
            transition: all 0 ease 0;
        }

        .menu-items li:hover > ul, #menu-secondary .menu-items li:hover > ul {
            margin: 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: The code you've shown would seem to have nothing to do with the buttons.

Comment: @isherwood : not so familiar with media queries, but I updated the code. Please see

Comment: Your media-query does not point to mobile devices.

Comment: @Andy am using this theme, please see the two css files on my WordPress theme. One is properly indented and other is not by the author. The id and the class name above are used in actual css. http://pastebin.com/BS1n92uB and http://pastebin.com/fFCeNLpw. Hoping for your consideration. Thanks

Comment: This might help you http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/